# Elisp: get quotation marks in format/echo

Tags: email, emacs, format, elisp, echo

In `.mailrc`, I would like to get the first row, but I get the second row

```
alias UIF "UIF Boxning <uifboxning@boxing.se>" # cool (written manually by me)
alias test_alias test_name <test_mail> # no quotation marks (written by below defun)
```

I am unsure if the problem is with `format` or `echo`. Have a look:

```
(defun save-mail-address (address name alias)
  "add an alias to the .mailrc file"
  (interactive "sMail address: \nsFull name: \nsAlias: ")
  (let ((compl-alias (format "alias %s \"%s \<%s\>\"" alias name address)))
    (shell-command (concat "echo " compl-alias " >> .mailrc")) ))
(defalias 'sma 'save-mail-address)
```

**Edit:**

OK, the goal is keep it like this:

```
alias long      "Long Long <long@long.long>"                    # 123456
alias s         "S S <s@s.s>"                                   # 1
```

Also, made I check so not to include duplicates:

```
(defun append-blanks (str len)
  (concat str (make-string (- len (length str)) ? )) )


(defun save-mail-address (mail name alias phone)
"add an alias to the .mailrc file"
(interactive "sMail mail: \nsFull name: \nsAlias: \nnPhone: ")
  (let*(
    (alias-alias (format "alias %s" alias))
    (alias-alias-blanks (append-blanks alias-alias 16))
    (mail-str (append-blanks (format "\"%s \<%s\>\"" name mail) 48))
    (line (format "%s%s\# %d\n" alias-alias-blanks mail-str phone))
    (file "~/.mailrc") )
      (with-temp-buffer
        (insert-file file)
        (if
          (search-forward alias-alias (point-max) t) ; t = return nil on fail
            (message (format "Error: The alias %s is already in use." alias))
            (progn
              (insert line)
              (sort-columns nil (point-min) (point-max)) ; nil = not reversed
              (write-file file nil) ))))) ; nil = inhibit confirm
```

Comment: The Lispy way of doing this would be to visit .mailrc in a buffer, add the text, save the buffer, kill it.

Comment: Right, although my solution works (with the below help), it has the annoying side effect that an empty `*Shell Command Output*` buffer is created. But, rather than redoing the whole thing, I think I'll just kill _that_ buffer last in the code instead and, next time, pick up your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ensure that variable arguments passed to a shell command are always appropriately escaped.

```el
(shell-command (concat "echo " (shell-quote-argument compl-alias)))
```

Comment: "You need to ensure that variable arguments passed to a shell command are always appropriately escaped." Haha, you don't say? But thanks for your solution, works like a charm.

Comment: Perhaps I should have written "the *way* to ensure... is to use `shell-quote-argument`".

Answer (score 1):

Just appending the text through Elisp would look like this:

```
(defun save-mail-address (address name alias)
  "add an alias to the .mailrc file"
  (interactive "sMail address: \nsFull name: \nsAlias: ")
  (let ((compl-alias (format "alias %s \"%s \<%s\>\"" alias name address)))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (insert compl-alias "\n")
      (write-region (point-min) (point-max) "~/.mailrc" t))))
```

Comment: Right, that is more consistent than mixing Elisp and shell tools. Maybe we could work out some rule of thumb out of this, like, if you are in setting A, but have more skills in setting B, you should not fall for the temptation to make a bridge but instead work to master A.

Comment: You might want to check that you don't add duplicates, too, and that the file is well-formed.  For that, you need to read the file, parse it, append, and write; or bail out if the parse fails or turns up a dupe.  This is a reasonably easy thing to add in Elisp, although it's certainly not hard to write a shell script, either.

Comment: @tripleee: Added the stuff you suggested as an edit. It seems to work. Take a look.